# Movie where second bomb was planted in ambulance

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for an action movie where:

- an explosion killed people and second bomb was planted in an ambulance which helped people after the first explosion
- it was a West vs East themed action movie
- there was a scene where some important guys drive in a convoy with "operating" speed
- the end of the movie contained some point where each of opposite side told that they will take revenge on the opponents
- it's a movie made after 2000

Comment: Batman: Dark Night Rises had a lot of similarities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The movie you're thinking of is **[The Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingdom_(film))**, released in 2007, and features a fictional but "based on true events" story in the Middle East.

From the plot section, regarding ambulances:

> While searching for evidence, Sergeant Haytham and Sykes discover the
>   second bomb was detonated in an ambulance. Fleury learns the brother
>   of one of the dead terrorists had access to ambulances and police
>   uniforms.

They move at "operational speed" to evade terrorists trying to bomb their vehicles with other bombs (cars traveling at their speed are likely trying to catch them if I recall correctly):

> On their way to King Khalid International Airport, Fleury grabs the
>   wheel from Sergeant Haytham, which allows them to partially evade the
>   collision of a speeding car with the first SUV in their convoy,
>   setting off a trunk full of explosives.

Regarding the matter of each side uttering phrases about taking revenge on the other:

> The scene cuts to Abu Hamza's daughter asking her own son what his
>   grandfather whispered to him as he was dying. The grandson tells her
>   mother, "Don't fear them, my child. We are going to kill them all," a
>   similar line Fleury whispered to Mayes, implying that this is a
>   never-ending, vicious cycle.